# How do I get select elements in one table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have a table named job in my db. Each job can be won by any provider.

My question is, do I need to create a new table for me to display jobs that has been won by a certain provider together with other details or should I just use the same table ?

**If so, how do I make sure that only the won jobs will be displayed in a separate table?**

Answer (score 0):

You can have a column that marks a job taken or not by let's say putting the id of the provider in the field or leaving it empty.

```
if ($row->taken=="") 
echo "Job available"; 
else echo $row->taken; // returns the id of the provider that has this job.
```

You can create another table where you have the provider id and the job he won, but by this you will have 3 tables. 1 with the providers, second with the jobs and third with the association which i believe is unnecessary here.

In the job table simply have a column that stands for the owner of the job.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your response. What I currently have are job and job proposal tables among others. What I plan is to display in each of the client and provider's page the job that has been awarded and job that has been won respectively.. Thing is, I can't just close a particular job that has already been won, because the client may want to hire another provider in the future.. here's what my job table originally has:  id , client_id, title, description, category_id, start_date, update_date_time, status, provider_id

Comment: From what you say i understand that a user can have 1 or more providers in the same time. I don't understand why is this a problem. You just add lines to the table as you have it now and you list by client or provider, like this: select provider_id from jobs where client_id = id. the echo all providers in a foreach for each provider_id

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in same table. if you want only particular column then give that column name into SELECT statement.